# How to read protobuf object in angular4 received in response of an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, arraybuffer, protobuf.js

Trying to read protobuf object instead of JSON object in angular4.

I found this [dcodeIO/protobufjs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js). But I don't understand how should I use this in my project?

I also tried installing the typings for protobufjs using typings install dt~protobufjs --global. When I import it, WebStorm says Cannot find module protobuf.

Any help! Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read protobuf object in angular4 using google-protobuf library.
import syntax is -

```
## import * as goog from 'google-protobuf'; ##
```

Reference github link is -
https://github.com/sparten11740/angular-protobuf-example